# How can I understand the order of the result of `numpy.narray.view` if I use it to view 2 `np.uint8` as 1 `np.uint16`?

Tags: python, numpy, binary, scientific-computing

Let's say I have an array `a` with two elements of data type `np.uint8`. And I'd like to view this array as if its contents were of data type `np.uint16`. So I use the `numpy.narray.view` method:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2], dtype=np.uint8)
print(a.view(np.uint16))
```

This results in `[513]`. However, I expected this to be:

```
a is [               1,               2 ]
       0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1, 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

                    _______________ _______________
So a.view should be 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 (binary 1 then 2)
                                                258
```

Why is it the other way round?

```
                         _______________ _______________
a.view really results in 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 (binary 2 then 1)
                                                     513
```

Why is the order this way?

Comment: [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).

Comment: Try `a.view('>u2')`

Comment: We gave you two small hints.  If you have figured it out from that, *you* should write an answer!  Answering your own questions is encouraged on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments from @WarrenWeckesser and @hpaulj I figured it out:

The two parts of the `numpy.uint16` which can be interpreted as two `numpy.uint8` don't necessarily lie "consecutively" in the memory. How the bytes are stored in the memory depends on the platform's endianness. For me, "consecutive" storing of the bytes seems intuitive, but is only true for big-endian platforms.

See the Wikipedia article for further information on endianness: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

My platform's endianness is little-endian. So if I call `a.view(np.uint16)` this is equivalent to `a.view("<u2")`. The last part of the `numpy.uint16` results in the first `numpy.uint8` and the other way round, which yields `513`. If I call `a.view(">u2")` I get the consecutive order for the two `numpy.uint8` and therefore `258` as the result.

`>` stands for big-endian, `<` stands for little-endian and `u2` makes it an 16bit unsigned integer.

For further reading, there are two suiting articles on SciPy.org...

- on how to deal with problems regarding endianness of data: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.byteswapping.html
- as well as the different data types one can use or create: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.dtypes.html